# How to access place and geo objects in tweet JSON object

Tags: python, json

I am currently trying to access the place names and coordinates of tweets from a json file created by twitter's API. While not all of my tweets include these attributes, some do and id like to collect them. my current approach is:

```
for line in tweets_json:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line.strip()) # only messages contains 'text' field is a tweet
        tweet_id = (tweet['id']) # This is the tweet's id
        created_at = (tweet['created_at']) # when the tweet posted
        text = (tweet['text']) # content of the tweet

        user_id = (tweet['user']['id']) # id of the user who posted the tweet
        hashtags = []
        for hashtag in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
            hashtags.append(hashtag['text'])

        lat = []
        long = []
        for coordinates in tweet['coordinates']['coordinates']:
            lat.append(coordinates[0])
            long.append(coordinates[1])

        country_code = []
        place_name = []
        for place in tweet['place']:
            country_code.append(place['country_code'])
            place_name.append(place['full_name'])

    except:
            # read in a line is not in JSON format (sometimes error occured)
        continue
```

As of right now, no attribute past Hashtags are being collected, Am I trying to access the attributes wrong? more information regarding the JSON object can be found here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

Comment: You haven't explained what is going wrong with your current approach. An example of a tweet line that you are working with, both with and without the geo data would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By wrapping all your code in a Try/Except block, you're passing over *every* error that occurs, including KeyErrors when trying to access a 'coordinates' that doesn't exist

If some of the parsed tweet dictionaries contain a key, and you want to collect them, you can do something like this:

```py
from json import JSONDecodeError

for line in tweets_json:
    # try to parse json
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line.strip()) # only messages contains 'text' field is a tweet
    except JSONDecodeError:
        print('bad json')   
        continue     

    tweet_id = (tweet['id']) # This is the tweet's id
    created_at = (tweet['created_at']) # when the tweet posted
    text = (tweet['text']) # content of the tweet

    user_id = (tweet['user']['id']) # id of the user who posted the tweet
    hashtags = []
    for hashtag in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
        hashtags.append(hashtag['text'])

    lat = []
    long = []

    # this is how you check for the presence of coordinates
    if 'coordinates' in tweet and 'coordinates' in tweet['coordinates']:
        for coordinates in tweet['coordinates']['coordinates']:
            lat.append(coordinates[0])
            long.append(coordinates[1])

    country_code = []
    place_name = []
    for place in tweet['place']:
        country_code.append(place['country_code'])
        place_name.append(place['full_name'])
```

Comment: With this, i receive a nonetype error with coordinates

Comment: had to alteryour if staements but this worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad you got something from it